# How do I change the text at the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

Here is an example for a `.lyx` file:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,american]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{SEC~\thesection.~#1}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat{name=\section, numberless} 
{\normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{12.8}{14}\selectfont}{}{0pt}{#1}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}

\part{Test1}

abcde

\section{Shalom}

\section{Test}

\rule[0.5ex]{0.4\columnwidth}{1pt}

\tableofcontents{}
\end{document}
```

As you can see - here is the output file:
[image]

How can I change the ToC that it will be:

```
SEC 1. Shalom                                      1
```

*(or other word instead of SEC)*

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to add SEC to the sections at TOC (and to add dots):

```
\titlecontents{section}[4.2em]{\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[SEC~\thecontentslabel]{3.5em}}
{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

adding this at the preamble.

The numbers (4.2 and 3.5) can be change for the spaces we want.
Here - `[SEC~\thecontentslabel]` is the value of what will be at the left side. (and of course we can add color to the font, I just want to show how I add text to it).
The lase argument `{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}` - adding the dots.

The result:
[image]

`\titlecontents` is of the package [titletoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc?lang=en) (page 15 at the Pack­age doc­u­men­ta­tion).